# Visa to transit in Vienna and Brussels for a Jordanian citizen

Tags: visas

I am travelling to Jordan-Amman from Liberia-Monrovia thru Brussels then Vienna to Amman, my nationality is Jordanian. Do I need visa to get thru two airports to my country. The flight to Brussels is on Brussels airway then on Austrian to Vienna (operated by Brussels), from Vienna to Amman on Austrian also.

Answer (score 0):

Since you will be transiting through two different Schengen airports, you need a type C Schengen visa. See [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area)